# How to find the first checkbox checked in a serie of checkboxs

Tags: php

I have 5 checkbox variables.

In order to avoid the problem of "undefined index" when checkbox was unchecked I've used this:

```
<input value="" name="checkbox1">
<input value="C1" name="checkbox1">
<input value="" name="checkbox2">
<input value="C2" name="checkbox2">
<input value="" name="checkbox3">
<input value="C3" name="checkbox3">
<input value="" name="checkbox4">
<input value="C4" name="checkbox4">
<input value="" name="checkbox5">
<input value="C5" name="checkbox5">

$col1 = $_POST['checkbox1'];
$col2 = $_POST['checkbox2'];
$col3 = $_POST['checkbox3'];
$col4 = $_POST['checkbox4'];
$col5 = $_POST['checkbox5'];
```

Now, I would like to write a query like this:

```
$query = "Select * from users where 1=1 ";

if($_POST['checkbox1'] !=="") {
$query.="And/OR col1='$col1'"; 
}
if($_POST['checkbox2'] !=="") {
$query.="And/OR col2='$col2'";
}
if($_POST['checkbox3'] !=="") {
$query.="And/OR col3='$col3'";
}
if($_POST['checkbox4'] !=="") {
$query.="And/OR col4='$col4'";
}
if($_POST['checkbox5'] !=="") {
$query.="And/OR col5='$col5'";
}
```

The problem is with the "And/OR".

If happend that the first checkbox was selected then it should be "And" if it was the second *from those checkboxs chosen* then "OR".Any idea's how to perform this?

For example: If $col2 checkbox was the first to be chosen and the user also chose $col4 checkbox then the $query should be:

```
"Select * users where 1=1 AND col2=$col2 OR col4=$col4"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like:

```
    $query = "Select * from users where 1=1 ";
    $chosen = false;
    if($_POST['checkbox1'] !=="") {
        $query.="And col1='$col1'"; 
        $chosen = true;
    }
    if($_POST['checkbox2'] !=="") {
        $query.= (($chosen) ? "OR" : "And") . " col2='$col2'";
        $chosen = true;
    }
    if($_POST['checkbox3'] !=="") {
        $query.= (($chosen) ? "OR" : "And") . " col3='$col3'";
        $chosen = true;
    }
    ...........................
```

Comment: Ginanin, could you explain the "And/Or" Part?

Comment: I edited my answer, have a look, it was left by mistake

Comment: @Toto88 - Any reason that answer is not useful for you ?

Comment: It closer to what I needed but it should be only or's after the first "And". Your code is putting "And" in the correct place but the others are "and" also. Any way to fix that? thank you!

Comment: @Toto88 I've just edited again, $chosen = true; in all condition so I won't allow duplicate and, try it and let me know if its still not working. remember you need to do this for all others condition which I not mentioned here

Comment: It's working. Thank you very much! Could you give me a littel explaination about the $query.= (($chosen) ? "OR" : "And") . " language2='$language2' ".
I'm a new at php so It will be very good for me to understand. I'm mainly asking about the "?" mark.

Comment: You're welcome, can you do up vote now ?
its ternary operator for more details - https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Comment: technicly I can't do a vote up (reputation etc). Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$query = "Select * from users where 1=1 ";
$where = "";
$where_arr = array();
if($_POST['checkbox1'] !=="") {
$where_arr[]=" col1='$col1'"; 
}
if($_POST['checkbox2'] !=="") {
$where_arr[]=" col2='$col2'";
}
if($_POST['checkbox3'] !=="") {
$where_arr[]=" col3='$col3'";
}
if($_POST['checkbox4'] !=="") {
$where_arr[]=" col4='$col4'";
}
if($_POST['checkbox5'] !=="") {
$where_arr[]=" col5='$col5'";
}

if(count($where_arr))
$where = " AND ".implode(" OR ", $where_arr);

$query .= $where;
```